# ¿Cómo hacer match entre un diccionario y una lista de listas en Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Lo que necesito hacer, es otorgar puntaje a las palabras de una frase que más se acercan a un concepto predefinido.Lo que he logrado hacer es exactamente eso pero solo con una frase. Adjunto ejemplo donde si la frase de respuesta contiene la palabra casa se le otorga 4 puntos, casita 3 y así.Si no hay coincidencias es cero y si hay más de una se suman.

```
puntaje = {'casa':4, 'casita':3, 'casona':2, 'hogar':1}
respuesta = ['Esta', 'es', 'mi', 'casa', 'mi', 'hogar']

suma=[]

for k in respuesta:
        if k in puntaje:
              suma.append(puntaje[k])

print sum(suma)
```

En este ejemplo me da como resultado **5** lo que es correcto ya que en la frase hay dos coincidencias con el diccionario: **Casa** que vale **4** y **Hogar** que vale **1**. Perfecto.

Mi problema ( aparte de no manejarse demasiado en python ) es que no logro hacer esto mismo con una lista de múltiples frases ( la idea es no hacer otro ciclo `for` aunque tampoco pude). He estado intentado con listas comprimidas pero no he logrado dar con el resultado.

Lo que necesito es analizar una lista como esta:

```
respuestas = [['Esta', 'es', 'mi', 'casa', 'mi', 'hogar'], 
['Esta', 'es', 'una', 'casa', 'grande'],
['Esto', 'parece', 'una', 'casona'],
['Esto' 'es' 'un' 'departamento'],
[...etc]]
```

Y el resultado esperado sería el siguiente:

```
{'Esta es mi casa mi hogar':5,
'Esta es una casa grande':4,
'Esto parece una casona':2,
'Esto es un departamento':0}
```

Comment: Deberías usar otro bucle para recorrer cada frase `for frase in respuesta : for k in frase : ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dos `for` vas a necesitar pero se puede hacer en una sola instrucción si quieres que el resultado sea ese (un diccionario con la frase como clave y la puntuación como valor). Simplemente usamos list comprehensions y el método `join` para cadenas:

```
puntaje = {'casa':4, 'casita':3, 'casona':2, 'hogar':1}

respuestas = [['Esta', 'es', 'mi', 'casa', 'mi', 'hogar'],
['Esta', 'es', 'una', 'casa', 'grande'],
['Esto', 'parece', 'una', 'casona'],
['Esto', 'es', 'un', 'departamento']]

res={' '.join(frase):sum((puntaje[palabra]
    for palabra in frase if palabra in puntaje))
    for frase in respuestas}

print(res)
```

Otra opción es usar el método `count()` para contar las apariciones de cada clave del diccionario en las listas:

```
puntaje = {'casa':4, 'casita':3, 'casona':2, 'hogar':1}

respuestas = [['Esta', 'es', 'mi', 'casa', 'mi', 'hogar'],
['Esta', 'es', 'una', 'casa', 'grande'],
['Esto', 'parece', 'una', 'casona'],
['Esto', 'es', 'un', 'departamento']]

res={' '.join(frase):sum((frase.count(palabra)*puntos
        for palabra, puntos in puntaje.items()))
        for frase in respuestas}

print(res)
```

Ambos formas se pueden hacer sin usar list comprehensions.
El primer código puede equivaler a :

```
puntaje = {'casa':4, 'casita':3, 'casona':2, 'hogar':1}

respuestas = [['Esta', 'es', 'mi', 'casa', 'mi', 'hogar'],
['Esta', 'es', 'una', 'casa', 'grande'],
['Esto', 'parece', 'una', 'casona'],
['Esto', 'es', 'un', 'departamento']]

res = dict()
for frase in respuestas:
    aux = 0
    for palabra in frase:
        if palabra in puntaje:
            aux += puntaje[palabra]
    res[' '.join(frase)] = aux

print(res)
```

Y el segundo a:

```
puntaje = {'casa':4, 'casita':3, 'casona':2, 'hogar':1}

respuestas = [['Esta', 'es', 'mi', 'casa', 'mi', 'hogar'],
['Esta', 'es', 'una', 'casa', 'grande'],
['Esto', 'parece', 'una', 'casona'],
['Esto', 'es', 'un', 'departamento']]

res = dict()
for frase in respuestas:
    aux = 0
    for palabra, puntos in puntaje.items():
        aux += frase.count(palabra)*puntos
    res[' '.join(frase)] = aux

print(res)
```

Y gracias a la 'magia' de Python en los cuatro casos sale:

> {'Esto es un departamento': 0, 'Esta es una casa grande': 4, 'Esta es mi casa mi hogar': 5, 'Esto parece una casona': 2}

**Nota**: Todo el código es válido para Python 2.7 y Python3.x

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Un poco más simple que la primera respuesta de @FJSevilla usando el método `get` de los diccionarios:

```
puntaje = {'casa':4, 'casita':3, 'casona':2, 'hogar':1}

respuestas = [
    ['Esta', 'es', 'mi', 'casa', 'mi', 'hogar'],
    ['Esta', 'es', 'una', 'casa', 'grande'],
    ['Esto', 'parece', 'una', 'casona'],
    ['Esto', 'es', 'un', 'departamento']
]

frases = (' '.join(palabras).lower() for palabras in respuestas)

res={ frase: sum(puntaje.get(palabra,0) for palabra in frase.split())
       for frase in frases }

print(res)
```